# Plotly Scatter Plot Gap in categorical y-axis

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

I cant find in [reference](https://plotly.com/python/reference/)  Plotly Python, information that I need.
Here my code:

```
fig_scatter = px.scatter(df_lv, x='frame', y='username', color='label_name', symbol='label_name',
                         title=f'{task_option}')# size='count_tag',
fig_scatter.update_traces(marker_size=10)
fig_scatter.update_layout(scattermode="group",scattergap=0.75,xaxis_range=[0, tasks_labels_df.frame.max()])
```

That my output:
[image]

I want less gap between two categorical variables in y-axis. So interactively I can in plot do less space between y-axis variables, but how to create this in default?
Plot that I want:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the categorical axis range is automatically set according to the number of distinct categories so that they span evenly across the entire axis length, ie.

```py
yrange = [-0.5, df_lv['username'].nunique() - 0.5]
```

You can "compress" the axis by increasing its range, eg. to span categories evenly across the lower half of the axis only, then multiply the max by 2 (before subtracting the 0.5 offset).

Here is a full example that produces the expected layout :

```py
df = px.data.medals_long()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="count", y="nation", color="medal", symbol="medal", template='plotly_dark')

yrange = [-0.5, 2*df['nation'].nunique() - 0.5]

fig.update_layout(scattermode="group",
                  scattergap=0.75,
                  yaxis_range=yrange,
                  xaxis_showgrid=False,
                  xaxis_zeroline=False
                  )
fig.show()
```

[image: screenshot]

You could also just increase the top margin (defaults to 80) so that the whole plot is compressed relative to the layout height, but I think it's not what you want.